# Jquery keydown event navigate picture slider

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, keydown

Hi I would like to add key board navigation to my css slider. Code of the slider are as below.

html

```
    <div class="imgdisplay">
      <ul>

        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="img1" name="slide" checked>
          <label for="img1"></label>
          <img src="work/legibile/render1.jpg">
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="img2" name="slide">
          <label for="img2"></label>
          <img src="work/legibile/render2.jpg">
        </li>

        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="img3" name="slide">
          <label for="img3"></label>
          <img src="work/legibile/render3.jpg">
        </li>
      </div>
```

css
     .imgdisplay input{
      display: none
     }

```
.imgdisplay label{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #BDBDBD;
 width:0.25em;
 height: 0.25em;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: #BDBDBD 2.5px solid;
 top:-1.5em;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 10
 }

.imgdisplay li:nth-child(1) label {
  left: 0em;
 }

.imgdisplay li:nth-child(2) label {
 left: 1.5em;
 }

.imgdisplay li:nth-child(3) label {
 left: 3em;
 }
.imgdisplay img {
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
 .imgdisplay li input:checked ~ img {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 10;
 }
```

I would like to navigate the slider by the left right arrow key. The basic idea is that the code first detect the checked  ID "img #". When user press the right arrow key,  with ID "img #+1" will be check. When user press the left arrow key,  with ID "img #-1" will be checked.

My question would be:
1. How do I make the code detect the ID of the  first.
2. I tried the following jquery code just to get familiar with keydown event however content of the page disappear and I do not know why.

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
  $("#img1").attr({"checked" });
  }
else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
  $("").attr({});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the id of radio inputs in this way

```
img_1, img_2, img_3
```

And execute the following code on document ready.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var checkedElmIdx =  parseInt($("[type='radio']:checked").attr("id").split("_")[1]);
   if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
       $("#img_"+(checkedElmIdx-1)).prop("checked", true);
   } else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        $("#img_"+(checkedElmIdx+1)).prop("checked", true);
   }
});
```

Comment: One quick question. Since "parseInt" will return integers from given string, why is there a need to split the ID for it to parse?

Comment: Please refer this link.[http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)